# Python 2.7 No module named _sqlite3 (no root access to machine, python is locally installed)?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

There might be other questions similar to this but, in my particular case, I don't have super user (sudo) access to the machine and I have locally installed Python 2.7.

```
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/spicmacay/.local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/spicmacay/.local/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
>>>
```

***UPDATE:*** When I run `./configure&& make`, I get:

```
make

running build
running build_ext
building dbm using gdbm
INFO: Can't locate Tcl/Tk libs and/or headers

Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_sqlite3           _tkinter           bsddb185        
dl                 imageop            sunaudiodev     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

running build_scripts
```

Comment: If you have compiled python you may have forgotten sqlite libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened me recently. You need to `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` (on debian - `sqlite-devel` possibly elsewhere) and recompile python.

Comment: you see here (NO root access)

Comment: you will need to find a binary of the libraries if possible and manually put them somewhere that python can pick them up when compiling

Answer (score 2):

Came to this issue also.. fixed by compiling Python and passing sqlite3 headers/libs during ./configure

[Python 2.7.3 _sqlite3 module is not being built after passing headers/libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143977/python-2-7-3-sqlite3-module-is-not-being-built-after-passing-headers-libraries/14145945#14145945)

Posted just in case anyone else has this issue in the future and does not have sudo access to a node.

Answer (score 1):

If you first `./configure` sqlite3 with a `--prefix` option, then `make` and `make install` it and then use the same `--prefix` when compiling Python, the Python installation will be able to magically find and use the sqlite3 you just installed.

```
cd sqlite-autoconf-3080100
./configure --prefix=/home/xdanek7/appscale/local
make
make install
cd ../Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/home/xdanek7/appscale/local
make
make install
```

Answer (score -3):

Try adding `sudo` before the command `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` to get rid of "NO root access"

i.e on terminal, write:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```